# What options are available for connecting new shed to power?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, shed

I am about to finish building a large shed (small garage) in Wisconsin and I'm considering my options for running power to it. The power company is WE Energies.

The shed is pretty close to a power pole but my house power runs off of a pole in the other corner of the lot. I would like to bury the line to the house someday and potentially upgrade my service a bit.

I don't think I have any circuits left in my current breaker box in the house so simply running a line from the house may prove to be more work than originally thought.

Details:

- Shed is 12x20 feet
- House is 1500sqft living area
- Shed is about 30 to 50 yards from the house but only about 5 yards from the power pole
- I don't need a lot of power (just lights and maybe one or two outlets)
- My breaker box does accept tandem breakers (I have installed one before) but I've heard they are sometimes illegal. I'm not sure what the code says in my area
- My breaker box has some sort of extension box off the side of it with a few more breakers in it
- Current service is either 100a or 150a service. I was considering upgrading to 200a at some point
- My bill says 723 kWh but doesn't list a service
- Appliances:

  - Dryer: LER4634BQ1 (4 amp motor, 23 amp heater and accessories)
  - Washer: LLR9245BQ1 (9.8 amp)
  - Furnace: NUGS075BG01
  - A/C: ???

Comment: How much power are you trying to run to it, and can you post a photo of the existing panel + its informational label/directory?  Also, how many square feet is it?

Comment: Will your panel accept tandem circuit breakers? Tandem breakers are 2 in 1 slot. Not all panels will accept them but if yours will purchasing a few tandem breakers will solve the space issue. A detached garage can have a separate service but the cost may end up being much higher than running from your main panel for just the install of the 2nd service. Plus the monthly service charge for the meter in my area it is 15-25 per month depending on the size of the service.

Comment: Also, can you figure out which size service you have? How big is the house (in square feet), and what's the watt or amp rating on the big fixed loads (electric WH, electric range, electric dryer, A/C or heat pump, dishwasher, and so on)?

Comment: My panel's informational label/directory is completely useless and wrong so I won't bother posting it

Comment: Just to see the panel would help. Don't worry about information written on it that could be wrong. Electricians are really bad at labelling panels anyways (say mechanics!).

Comment: **Option 1:** Pay for a second service to the shed, and have a service drop, meter, and panel installed at the shed. **Option 2:** Supply the shed through the existing service.  ***Option 2a:*** Install tandem breakers (if supported by your panel) to free up space in the panel. ***Option 2b:*** Move some of the circuits to a secondary panel, to free up space to feed the secondary panel. Then supply the shed from the second panel.  **Option 3:** Install solar/wind/generator/etc. power in the shed.